# Copy a user from one WordPress site to another

Tags: users, user-registration, user-access

Is it possible to copy a user from one WordPress site to another?

I copied the record from the `user` table and all the related records from the `usermeta` table (12 records by default) but I think something else is needed. I get this message upon login: `You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.`

The reason I need this is I have 4 users I'd like to grant access to on a new site but use their credentials from the current site.

Comment: does this include their password?

Comment: For 4 users, you'd be better off just creating new accounts for them. There's more to migrating users than just the user records.

Comment: Yes, @TomJNowell, I'd like to keep their passwords.

Comment: @vancoder, thanks. I guess I'll have to recreate them then and set new passwords. I am looking into implementing Active Directory, but would still like to know how to migrate a number of users, for future reference.

Comment: @vancoder I don't think that's true. I don't see why won't that work. All the things related to user creation is in those two tables. I successfully copied one user this way.

Comment: They won't be able to keep their passwords unless you have the same keys and salts in `wp-config.php`, changing them would invalidate all of your existing users passwords. I would ***strongly*** recommend against this for security reasons, if your client demands it then your client is being unreasonable and should be told no point blank. Tell them it is not possible

Comment: I agree with @TomJNowell. The only problem will be with password. But still you should avoid such method for real user. I don't want to be added to a new site without me knowing. But if you want to do this to add your clients( I mean the owners of the website ), I don't see any problem. If the salt is different, you still have to reset password though.

Comment: @TomJNowell changing salts invalidates cookies (requiring to login again), but it does not invalidate password hashes.

Comment: If you want the same passwords, just make the users with the same account name & random password, then access the database and just copy the `user_pass` column. It's located in `wp_users` table. This way it will be the same pass. Not the best way but if there only 4 users, it's the fastest way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure the new ID of the user in the user table matches the foreign key in the usermeta.

Also a word of caution regarding your comment on Active Directory integration. For public facing websites be extremely careful, you could inadvertantly expose you domain controller information to the web. You might want to consider additional security precautions around the login and admin pages, for example limiting access to certain IP addresses or dual authentication.